# Create report via email powershell

Tags: actionscript-3, powershell

```
function Get-MyLoggedOnUsers
{
 param([string]$Computer)
 Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $Computer | Select Antecedent -Unique | %{“{0}{1}” -f $_.Antecedent.ToString().Split(‘”‘)[1], $_.Antecedent.ToString().Split(‘”‘)[3]}
}
```

is there a way I get email alerts for this and add more queries like client name client ip, date and time etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to be compiled into memory, so when you run this as a script, you need to have the Function declaration (the whole `Function Get-My {`, then all the way to the final `}` ) up top, then later on in your code you can run `Get-MyLoggedOnUsers` and see a list like this one, of your unique users.

```
Antecedent
----------
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="BEHEMOTH",Name="FoxDeploy"
```

With PowerShell, we can store the output of anything to screen in a variable, and use that instead.  So in my code, I'm running your function, capturing it in a variable, and then using that as the body of an e-mail message.  I hope the added detail helps.

---

PowerShell has a built-in cmdlet, `Send-MailMessage` which you can use if you have an open SMTP forwarder/e-mail server in your environment, like Exchange or something else.  You can also use it to send GMail messages.

People have built PowerShell modules for practically every e-mail provider too, so you could use the PSGmail module to just pipe your cmdlet.  If you want to use the built-in cmdlet of Send-MailMessage, you'd run the following.

```
$MailMessage= Get-MyLoggedOnUsers
Send-MailMessage -body $MailMessage -Port 465 -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com `
 -Credential (get-credential) -to Whoever@gmail.com -From Yourname@gmail.com
```

This will prompt you for your Gmail credentials, and should send the message out.  Make sure to type in the right e-mail address for the -To and -From parameters.

As an example of using the built in tool.

Comment: Can you please add more details I am Poweshelly challenged

Comment: If you're using the SMTP.google.com addres, you can only email other @gmail.com addresses.  If you'd like not to have that limitation, there are a whole world of other ways to send e-mail.

Comment: wil try something else > my need is to get email notification whenever user logins to a computer with client name, user computer name etc